# C strings and character input, comparison

Tags: c, string

I am learning c programing, for exercise I found a task to solve.
It is something like a game hanging where someone chooses a word and other person guess letters. I have to check how many given words could be a correct answer to the choosen word.

Input:

3 3 // numbers n and m n-number of words to compare, m-number of letters checked

A C D // m letters separate by space

--CA  // word that is given to guess

KUCA  // n words to be checked if they match in this case "--CA"

ZGRADA // words are separated by enter(\n)

MACA  // in this case "MACA" does not match "--CA" because there was a "A" in the guessed letters but not on the second dash meant for some letter

Output: 1

Idea is to check if the lenghts are the same if they are it should check if current character is "-" if so it should check every of m characters (guessed letters) if they match current one if so rez--;(sol--;)(before was declared rez=n;)

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n=0,i=0,m=0,j=0,k=0,duzina=0,rez=0,br=0;
char slova[26], rec[30], pot[30],c;

scanf("%d %d\n",&n,&m);

br = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
    if ( c != ' ' ) { slova[br] = c; br++; }
}
slova[br] = '\0';
br = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
  rec[br] = c;
  br++;
}
rec[br] = '\0';
rez=n;
duzina=strlen(rec);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    br=0;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
        pot[br] = c;
        br++;
    }
    pot[br] = '\0';
    if(duzina!=strlen(pot))
        rez--;
    else{
        for(j=0;j<duzina;j++){
            if(rec[j]=='-'){
                for(k=0;k<m;k++){
                    if(pot[j]==slova[k]){
                        rez--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if(rec[j]!=pot[j])
                    rez--;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("%d",rez);

return 0;
}
```

So my problem is in the wrong answer, and I don't know why.

Code works for example above but for this one it shows -8, it should 3:

10 5

A I L B X

--A--AB-X

PUAQFABHX

IIAFWABIX

MHAKVABPX

BQAXWABWX

TEAUIAB

PCALIABLX

RRAYHAEKJ

NWNKSGBNP

ZOCZKJWZR

ROAJRABZX

Comment: You forgot to add what the actual problem/question is. If it's a general "how is my code" question, you might want to post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: `getchar` returns `int`, not `char`. `scanf` returns a useful value that you should be captured and checked. Your while loops to read lines are a reimplementation of `gets` that is even worse than `gets` because at least `gets` checks for EOF; why not use the `fgets` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` portion of the following code:

```
if(duzina!=strlen(pot))
  rez--;
else{
  for(j=0;j<duzina;j++){
    if(rec[j]=='-'){
      for(k=0;k<m;k++){
        if(pot[j]==slova[k]){
          rez--;
          break; // <-- This will break out of the 'for-k' loop
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      if(rec[j]!=pot[j])
        rez--;  // <-- Are you missing a 'break' here?
    }
  }
}
```

After `rez` is decremented, you need to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int n=0,i=0,m=0,j=0,k=0,duzina=0,rez=0,br=0;
char slova[26], rec[30], pot[30],c;
short booli=1;

scanf("%d %d\n",&n,&m);

br = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
    if ( c != ' ' ) { slova[br] = c; br++; }
}
slova[br] = '\0';
br = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
  rec[br] = c;
  br++;
}
rec[br] = '\0';


rez=n;
duzina=strlen(rec);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    br=0;
    booli=1;// this is the line that i forgot, that caused all the trouble.
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ){
        pot[br] = c;
        br++;
    }
    pot[br] = '\0';
    if(duzina!=strlen(pot))
        rez--;
    else{
        for(j=0;j<duzina;j++){
            if(rec[j]=='-'){
                for(k=0;k<m;k++){
                    if(pot[j]==slova[k]){
                        rez--;
                        booli=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(booli==0) break;/*this is for checking if the for-k loop was ended with break;*/
            }
            else{
                if(rec[j]!=pot[j]){
                    rez--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("%d",rez);

return 0;
}
```

Thaks to agbinfo for saying that I that I need second break;